# setting a google analytics code for Dialog boxes Yes or no

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I am trying to fire google analytic code when the Dialog box is prompted with YES or NO. Could you please show me any resolutions. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far? Any code attempts, etc. It helps to see what you've done so that we can better help you.

Comment: Are you trying to send an event?